# Date matching regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match the year in the following set of data:

```
2014-15 blah
14-15 blah
2015 blah
12/1/2015
2015/25/1
blah 2015-2016
blah-2008
blah 14-15
```

It should match all either 4 digit, or 2 digit years. Any time the year is 2 digits, it will be the only number present in the string.

This is the regex I have so far, `(\d{2,4})(?:\s|-|/|$)`, but the issue is that it matches the day/month if it's a two digit day/month. If it's in the form of `day/month/year` or `year/month/day`, the year will always be the full four digits.

This needs to work with Python's `re` module.

Comment: If you hope to match all those cases, you will need logic beyond what regex alone will do. There will always be ambiguity between a 2 digit year and month and day.

Comment: @anubhava That's only if it's in the form of `day/month/year` or `year/month/day`. It might be 2 digits other than that. @dawg Alright, I wasn't sure.

Comment: Is it PCRE? Just curious if lookbehind is available and other more advanced features.

Comment: @stribizhev It's the `re` module in Python, I'm not sure what that supports.

Comment: So in `14-15` what should it match?

Comment: What is the expected output for each line ?

Comment: Please check [`\b\d{4}\b|(?<!\b\d{4}/)(?<!\b\d{2}/)\b\d{2}\b(?!/\d{1,2}/\d{4}\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/yJ2gB7/2).

Comment: @stribizhev Yup, that's exactly what I needed! Thank you! If you want to post an answer, I'll give you the accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\b\d{4}\b|(?<!\b\d{4}/)(?<!\b\d{2}/)\b\d{2}\b(?!(?:/\d{1,2})?/\d{4}\b)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yJ2gB7/5)

The regex will match 2 alternatives:

- `\b\d{4}\b` - Any 4-digit sequence as a whole word
- `(?<!\b\d{4}/)(?<!\b\d{2}/)\b\d{2}\b(?!(?:/\d{1,2})?/\d{4}\b)` - Any 2 digits as a whole word that is not preceded with 4- or 2-digit word and is not followed with 2-digit/4-digit whole word.

Comment: It matches both `10` and `2015` in `10/2015` but may be this is how OP wants.

Comment: That actually is an issue for me. :/ It matches all my other test cases perfectly, but it matches `10`, and `2015` in `1/10/2015`. It should only match `2015`.

Comment: @MorganThrapp: I updated the expression, please check.

Comment: @stribizhev Yup, perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your requirement correctly you can use this lookahead based regex:

```
\b(?:\d{4}(?=/|$)|\d{2}\d{2}?(?=[\s-]|$))
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
\b                      # word boundary
(?:                     # start non-capturing group
\d{4}(?=/|$)            # match 4 digit that should be followed by a / or end of string
|                       # alternation
\d{2}\d{2}?(?=[\s-]|$)  # match 2 or 4 digits that are followed by a space or -
                        # or end of input
)                       # end non-capturing group
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yF1pK4/6)